# How do I connect a ProGet Feed as an remote feed in Artifactory rev 7.7.8

Tags: nuget, repository, artifactory, proget

The documentation is a bit unclear on both JFrogs webpage as well as in Inedos webdocs.

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/NuGet+Repositories

https://docs.inedo.com/docs/proget/feeds/nuget

Because of the way Artifactory setups their remote nuget feeds, it's easy to misunderstand.

I've tried using the following the url field:

```
http://<url path to server>:<port>/nuget/<repo name>/
```

with

```
Packages
```

in the NuGet Download Context Path field. The field has to contain something. But that's not correct. Nor is moving the repo name to the Download Context Path field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is rather simple .. after two days of testing ..

In the URL field:

```
http://<fqdn or url>:<port>/nuget/<nugetFeedName>/
```

NuGet Download Context Path

```
Package
```

NuGet Feed Context Path is empty

NuGet v3 Feed URL is empty

If it's an internal feed, remember to remove proxy settings under advanced tabs.

**REMEMBER TO SET PERMISSIONS TO THE Remote repositories!**

Also, make sure that v3 is disabled in the ProGet feed

Comment: If anyone is curious, I made this post because the top result on google is not helpful.